# Restful webservice with XML in Salesforce

Tags: visualforce, trigger, webservices

I am trying to write this below xml from Contact object.Problem is compostion of the xml with nested childs is really complex.Can you help understand to demistfy this problem.

```
"<request version='1.0'> <header> <office>SDC</office> <user>Userid</user> <password>*****</password> </header> <insert> <Contact> <LastName>Test1</LastName> <FirstName>Test</FirstName> <Title>Dr.</Title> <TaxID>123456789</TaxID> <Person> <Dob>1959-03-30</Dob> <Gender>1</Gender> <Occupation>Baker</Occupation> <JobTitle>Dough Boy</JobTitle> <Marital>1</Marital> <Salary>15000</Salary> </Person> </Contact> </insert> </request>"
```

Indented version:

```
<request version="1.0">
    <header>
        <office>SDC</office>
        <user>Userid</user>
        <password>*****</password>
    </header>
    <insert>
        <Contact>
            <LastName>Test1</LastName>
            <FirstName>Test</FirstName>
            <Title>Dr.</Title>
            <TaxID>123456789</TaxID>
            <Person>
                <Dob>1959-03-30</Dob>
                <Gender>1</Gender>
                <Occupation>Baker</Occupation>
                <JobTitle>Dough Boy</JobTitle>
                <Marital>1</Marital>
                <Salary>15000</Salary>
            </Person>
        </Contact>
    </insert>
</request>
```

Here is the code:

```
public class RestDemoController {
    public String policyid { get; set; }
    public String CName { get; set; }
    public String LName { get; set; }
    public String FName { get; set; }
    public String address { get; set; }
    public PageReference submit() {
      sendRequest();
        return null;
   }    
     public void sendRequest(){
          XmlStreamWriter w = new XmlStreamWriter();
          w.writeStartDocument('utf-8','1.0');
          w.writeStartElement('null','request', '1.0'); 
          w.writeStartElement(null, 'Header', null); //this will start with <Header> in XML
          w.writeStartElement(null, 'office', '****');
          w.writeEndElement();
          w.writeStartElement(null, 'user','*****');
          w.writeEndElement();
          w.writeStartElement(null, 'password','*****');
          w.writeEndElement();
         // w.writeCharacters(a.AccountExternalID__c);
          w.writeEndElement();
          w.writeEndElement();
          String xmlOutput = w.getXmlString();
          w.close();
        System.debug('XML Output**********'+xmlOutput);
        String endpoint='www.google.com';
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setEndpoint(endpoint);
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
        req.setBody(xmlOutput);

        Http http = new Http();
        HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
       } 
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code you have so far? Where are you having the problem? How are you generating the XML?

Comment: This is the error i am getting from the above code:System.XmlException: Prefix cannot be null

Comment: Actually there is no prefix in the xml.

Comment: Looking at the code you added to the question, two of the 3 parameters in methods like writeStartElement relate to namespaces which you are not using. To add content to an element you have to use writeCharacters. See https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?id=906F00000008ybEIAQ for an example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question appears to be how to create the XML. The simplest Apex API for this is the [DOM API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_xml_dom.htm). You create the nesting yourself by creating a root document and adding child nodes. When you have built the tree in this form you can invoke the `toXmlString()` method to produce the XML string.

See the "XmlNode Example" in the above link and/or Google for many examples posted in blogs etc. Generally outputting XML is easier than parsing XML.

**PS**

The sample code added to the question is using `XmlStreamWriter`. When not using namespaces lots of nulls need passing (null not 'null'); to add content inside elements the `writeCharacters` method must be used. This API requires more lines of code than the DOM approach and is harder to get right: it is only necessary to resort to this API for very large documents. But having started with it I guess you may want to continue - see e.g. [Creating an XML with Xmlstreamwriter](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?id=906F00000008ybEIAQ) for a working example of how to use the API.